# Rewriting a VB.NET Lambda expression as a C# statement

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I downgraded my app from version 4 of the framework to version 4 and now I want to implement this VB.NET lambda function statement (which works on 3.5)

```
Dim colLambda As ColumnItemValueAccessor = Function(rowItem As Object) General_ItemValueAccessor(rowItem, colName)
```

and rewrite it in C#. This was my attempt:

```
ColumnItemValueAccessor colLambda = (object rowItem) => General_ItemValueAccessor(rowItem, colName);
```

When I did this, I get the following error:

```
Error   14  One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll? C:\Source\DotNet\SqlSmoke\SqlSmoke\UserControls\ScriptUserControl.cs    84  73  SqlSmoke
```

However, when I downgraded the app from version 4.0 of the framework to 3.5 (because our users only hae 3.5 and don't have rights to install 4.0). when I did this, the reference to "Microsoft.CSharp" was broken.

Can I rewrite the VB.NET command in C# using syntax that is valid in C# 3.5 as I was able to in VB.NET? What would the syntax be?

I'm thinking that if I want to stay on 3.5, which is a must, then I have to write this code in VB.NET because it looks like C# got this functionality after VB.

```
namespace BinaryComponents.SuperList
{
    public delegate object ColumnItemValueAccessor(object rowItem);
}

private object General_ItemValueAccessor(DataRow rowItem, object colName)
{
    DataRow rowPerson = (DataRow)rowItem;
    return rowPerson[colName.ToString()].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us how exactly **ColumnItemValueAccessor** and **General_ItemValueAccessor** are defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic typing in C# is new to .Net 4.0.

Don't use dynamic.

Comment: Can you explain? I'm a bit new to this functionality. Perhaps, change the syntax of the line?

Comment: Perhaps you're using "dynamic" keyword somewhere in you program.

Comment: I used a code converter and didn't realize that "string colName = DataCol.ColumnName;" was previously defined as "dynamic colName = DataCol.ColumnName;." I thought the statements that I posted were using "dynamic typing." Until you mentioned that dynamic was a keyword, I searched for it and -- bingo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to have the right using

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that one of the types don't match.  Change the delegate parameter type from `object` to `DataRow`:

```
public delegate object ColumnItemValueAccessor(DataRow rowItem);
```

As AVD noted, you also need to fix the syntax on the lambda expression (the type `object` for `rowItem` is implied, it shouldn't be specified there):

```
ColumnItemValueAccessor colLambda = (rowItem) => General_ItemValueAccessor(rowItem, colName);
```

The key point is that when you write a lambda expression for the delegate type `ColumnItemValueAccessor`, the parameters and the return type of the lambda must match the delegate.